# JAVA OptionPane.showMessageDialog output formatting for decimal

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, number-formatting, decimalformat

I am very new to Java and playing with displaying a message with GUI. So if use the console

```
System.out.printf("Your total montly bill is $%.2f",  totalCost);
```

gives me the output with decimal the way it should. I am trying to do the same thing with this, but I get more digits after the decimal because totalCost is a type double. How can I format the output to only show two digits after the decimal? Thanks.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your monthly payment is " + totalCost);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Your monthly payment is $%.2f",  totalCost));
```

Comment: Ha, that was simple! Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
double d = 1.234567;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your monthly payment is " + df.format(d));
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

[Class DecimalFormat API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

***You can also do:***
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Your monthly payment is " + totalCost);

Answer (score 0):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
                String hour = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input your hourly salary: ");
                double hr = Double.parseDouble(hour);
                double dr = hr * 8;             
                double wr = hr * 40;
                double mr = hr * 160;
                double yr = mr * 12;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yearly: " + df.format(yr) + " / " + "Monthly: "
                    + df.format(mr) + " / " + "Weekly: "+ df.format(wr) + " / " + "Hour: " + df.format(hr),
                    "Yearly Salary Calculator by the hour", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, icon);
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. What is `df`? How to use it in case OP described?

Comment: You can display more information by linking them with the plus (+) sign, then you can continue with the JOptionPane format (null, message, title, message type, icon) by separating all the elements with the comma (,). "/" is just a spacer to distribute the answer in a more presentable manner.

Comment: Still - without knowledge of what `df` is in your code sample, your answer is not useful at all. Also - there already was an example of using `DecimalFormat`.

Comment: df is just the variable I assigned to DecimalFormat. When you declare your variable it will look like: DecimalFormat df(or whatever you choose) = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); Or whatever format you choose as an argument.